# Preparing Unit Test for events

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, unit-testing

I want to prepare unit test for code written on events (such as button click or other events) or for function getting called inside an event.
How will I pass i/p parameters from unit test method that are being read in events from controls like textbox, dropdownlist , etc. and function getting called inside event is reading values from  controls .
Can we prepare unit test cases for such functions?

Comment: You can't really unit test presentation-specific code because you can't interact with a UI that doesn't exist. You should write your code in such a way that the presentation-specific code is isolated as much as possible and you can then do testing specific to the UI.